# Libraries not loading on form load- CRM 2016

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are upgrading from CRM 2011 to CRM 2016 on premise.
I have all the libraries added on the form load in address entity form but those libraries aren't being loaded at the first time ans showing error message 'Mscrm' is undefined in the below code snippet and page.

```
     <script language="JavaScript">
    window.setTimeout(ribbonRefreshForArticle, 2000);
    function ribbonRefreshForArticle() {
    var uri = Mscrm.CrmUri.create(window.location.href);
    if (uri.get_query() != null && uri.get_query()["etc"] == Mscrm.InternalUtilities.EntityTypeCode.KbArticle) {
    refreshRibbon();
    }
}
</script>
```

Page- http://myOrg/testDev/userdefined/edit.aspx?_CreateFromId={447AE3EE-2727-E511-84E4-005056B33BEB}&_CreateFromType=2&_gridType=1071&etc=1071&id={858C47D7-62AE-43DE-A13B-2F648EFD111E}&pagemode=iframe&rskey={03315B35-4585-4447-A4D2-059CF79CA0FD}

Need help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your snippet,  You're showing the JS within the context of an HTML script tag, but you're defining it as being called from the Form Load.

If you have an html web resource, you must first add the ClientGlobalContext `<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx?type=script" type="text/javascript"></script>` ("../" may vary depending on your resource path), and then wait for your document to be ready:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    onLoad();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your libraries in the file that contains your javascript
like:

```
<head>
    <script src="cs_jsQuery" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cs_CimailXrmProximaIncident" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```